# how to process file names of a directory in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to list the most recent folder in a directory that does not end with the word 'patch'

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do (        
    // some if loop to ensure that newest is not set to something that ends with "-patch".
set newest=%%a
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /o-d /ad ^|findstr /v /e /c:"-patch"  2^>nul') do (            
 set "newest=%%~fa"
 goto :break
)
:break
echo newest : %newest%
```

Comment: I can't use pipes within for (). Can you?

Comment: you can if they are escaped with `^`

Comment: does not work, the result is empty string. However the folder does contain other directories which does not end with '-patch'.

Comment: could you check it now?

Comment: aaaghh..You need directory name.Fixed now

Comment: is it not possible to just check something like fileName.indexOf('patch') == -1 set to newest

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /od /ad ^|findstr /evi "patch"  2^>nul') do set "RecentFolder=%%~a"
echo %RecentFolder%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enableextensions
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do (
    set "a=%%a"
    if /i not "!a:~-5!"=="patch" set "file=%%a"
)
```

`file` will contain desired folder name.

Comment: Ordering with `/od` may fail. If names are suitable, use `/on`.

Comment: does not work. Still the directory with '-patch' is listed as the most recent one.